# Running Macro script from another sheet resulting in error

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code which is intended to find a button inside another worksheet via some VBA script,  if the buttons text contains "Hide all Rows", then execute code, else execute other code.

The if statement works and recognizes the button text, but it doesn't seem to want to recognize the macro name in the targetworkbook.  I get the error 'The item with the specified name wasn't found'

I checked the targetworkbook macro name and it is correct,
code is below, am I doing something wrong here?

```
Sub MapValues(targetworkbook As Workbook, TargetSheet As Worksheet)
Dim shp as shape
Set shp = TargetSheet.Shapes("Button13" & TargetSheet.Name)

With targetworkbook
   If shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Hide All Rows" Then
      targetworkbook.Application.Run "'" & targetworkbook.Name & "'!showAllRows"
   Else
      targetworkbook.Application.Run "'" & targetworkbook.Name & "!hideAllRows"
      targetworkbook.Application.Run "'" & targetworkbook.Name & "!showAllRows"
   End If
End With


End Sub()
```

Comment: `Application.Run "'" & targetworkbook.Name & "' !ShowAllRows"`

Comment: By default Form buttons have spaces in their names - are you usre it's not: `TargetSheet.Shapes("Button 13")` instead? (though I'd use `TargetSheet.Buttons("Button 13")`)

Comment: I discovered the issue to the original problem and corrected it using a change in syntax, and assigning the shape to its own value, however I have another problem now.  Check the section above.

Comment: In your 'with' statement, do you need `targetworkbook.Application.Run...` and `targetworkbook.name`? You should be able to remove "targetworkbook" since you're using a "with" statement.  If you want to keep them, you don't need the "with" statement.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with the text "Button13". Double check that it's not really something like "Button 13". The easiest way to do that is in the immediate window type

```
?sheet1.Shapes(1).name
```

and continue with 2,3,4 etc. until you get your name.